# .net core 2.0 logging inside Kubernetes pod console

Tags: c#, docker, kubernetes, .net-core

I wrote few web APIs in .net core 2.0 and deployed it using a docker container inside a Kubernetes cluster. I am using the below logging configuration but can't see any logs inside the Kubernetes pod console. Am I missing something here?:

Logging section in appsettings.json & appsettings.Development.json

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "IncludeScopes": true,
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Debug",
      "System": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Information"
    },
    "Console": {
      "LogLevel": {
        "Default": "Information",
        "System": "Information",
        "Microsoft": "Information"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Inside Program.cs:

```
public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args)
{
    return new WebHostBuilder()
        .UseKestrel()
        .ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostingContext, config) =>
        {
            var env = hostingContext.HostingEnvironment;

            config.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
                .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true);

            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                var appAssembly = Assembly.Load(new AssemblyName(env.ApplicationName));
                if (appAssembly != null)
                {
                    config.AddUserSecrets(appAssembly, optional: true);
                }
            }

            config.AddEnvironmentVariables();

            if (args != null)
            {
                config.AddCommandLine(args);
            }
        })
        .ConfigureLogging((hostingContext, logging) =>
        {
            logging.AddConfiguration(hostingContext.Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
            logging.AddConsole();
            logging.AddDebug();
        })
        .UseDefaultServiceProvider((context, options) =>
        {
            options.ValidateScopes = context.HostingEnvironment.IsDevelopment();
        })
        .UseStartup<Startup>()
        .Build();
}
```

Example of logging in other classes:

```
_logger.LogInformation("This log should go in kubernetes pod console");
```

Comment: are you facing issues while you run your code from the visual studio 's debug mode?

Comment: I'm running into the same thing.  It seems like the ILogger is not going to Kubernetes STDOUT where it would show up in k8s logging mechanisms.  For me, this is on a Linux Ubuntu container.

Comment: Can you get logs when you run the Container locally? E.g. `docker run <image>` and `docker logs <container>`?

Comment: I can't reproduce this using the exact same code as posted above with .netcore 2.1/minikube. Is there a reproducible sample code to investigate?

Answer (score 3):

Have you attempted to DI common third-party packages built for powerful logging instead? That might suit your needs! The code below shows how Serilog is injected in `Program.cs` and can be used to output its logs through several channels of your choice (I'm personally using minikube locally on macOS along with a staging environment on GCP).

```
WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .UseSerilog((context, configuration) =>
                {
                    configuration
                        .MinimumLevel.Debug()
                        .MinimumLevel.Override("Microsoft", LogEventLevel.Warning)
                        .MinimumLevel.Override("System", LogEventLevel.Warning)
                        .MinimumLevel.Override("Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication", LogEventLevel.Information)
                        .Enrich.FromLogContext()
                        .WriteTo.Console(
                            outputTemplate:
                            "[{Timestamp:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} {Level}] {SourceContext}{NewLine}{Message:lj}{NewLine}{Exception}{NewLine}",
                            theme: AnsiConsoleTheme.Literate);
                })
```

The desired output from the above would look something like that in Kubernetes:

```
 xxxxx@iMac  ~/Projects/xxxxx   xxxxbranch/xxx-xxx  kubectl logs xxxx-xxxx-6b9dd8dc67-vc9ch
[2020-08-04 12:11:37 Warning] Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.Repositories.FileSystemXmlRepository
Storing keys in a directory '/xxxxxxxxx/.aspnet/DataProtection-Keys' that may not be persisted outside of the container. Protected data will be unavailable when container is destroyed.

[2020-08-04 12:11:37 Warning] Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.XmlKeyManager
No XML encryptor configured. Key {xxxxxx} may be persisted to storage in unencrypted form.

[2020-08-04 12:11:37 Warning] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel
Overriding address(es) 'https://+:8081'. Binding to endpoints defined in UseKestrel() instead.

Hosting environment: Production
Content root path: /app
Now listening on: https://0.0.0.0:8081
Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
```

These outputs are also stashed in Google Cloud's Logging dashboard.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try adding `"IncludeScopes": true` under the `Console` key in your appsettings?

```
"Console": {
  "IncludeScopes": true
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "System": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Information"
    }
}
```

I was able to stream logs running this `kubectl` command:

> kubectl logs --follow -c [containername] [podname]

Reponse from running pod:

```
←[40m←[32minfo←[39m←[22m←[49m: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Now listening on: http://[::]:80
←[40m←[32minfo←[39m←[22m←[49m: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
←[40m←[32minfo←[39m←[22m←[49m: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Hosting environment: Development
←[40m←[32minfo←[39m←[22m←[49m: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Content root path: /app
```